# Writing a Script for MySQL or Java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I need to make a data file to hold two empty tables with many fields
I have been successful at making a MySQL 5.5 Table with its DOS style IDE OK.
And MySQL registers with NetBeans very well.

Can I make a script to build this from with in my program
or can this be done directly in Java and get a Java file to read file parameters as its executed to create the data base file name.

I have no idea what direction to take to do this and what's possible.
I'm writing in Java and Delphi and Delphi has no MySQL support.
Has any one done anything similar before and how did they do it

The database is to hold 70 meduim size pictures, How slow will updates be when accessing pictures and should I use JPEG or BMP storage for wireless Java apps?
Can Java manage JPEG files and display them?

Comment: you can easily execute DDL (your script to create database) using jdbc in java.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of questions in one post. Let me try to address each point individually.

1. Yes, you can write Java code to create your MySQL database for you. On the other hand, tools such [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) can do this for you—you just need to learn its XML configuration syntax.
2. Lots of people have successfully written Java and Delphi code to access MySQL databases. If I recall correctly, at the very least Delphi supports MySQL access through ODBC, if not, through 3rd-party custom components.
3. Java can store & retrieve JPEG images to/from a database just like any other language, though, in practice, I wouldn't do it that way. Rather, I'd store the images themselves in the file system and just store their locations in the database. RDBMSes weren't really built with handling large binary BLOBs in mind.
4. How would you like to display the images? If on screen via a desktop client, then, yes, Java's Swing components can easily and readily display JPEG, even GIF & PNG images. If via a Web browser or remote client, then it's really just a matter of serving the images over HTTP to the browser/client app.